# TypeError: 'long' object is not callable

Tags: python

I have steam coming out of my head now but I can't figure out what is wrong with my code.
Here are the relevant lines:

```
 try:
   outport = record_dict[id][hash_ % len(record_dict[id])]
 except:
   fp.write("Problem-"+str(type(record_dict[id]))+"\n")
   fp.write("Problem-"+str(record_dict[id])+"\n")
   fp.write("Problem-"+str(len(record_dict[id]))+"\n")
```

Here is the error I get:

```
  File "xxxx.py", line 459, in yyyyy
    fp.write("Problem-"+str(len(record_dict[id]))+"\n")
  TypeError: 'long' object is not callable
```

Inside file pointed by fp:

```
Problem-<type 'list'>
Problem-[5, 6, 7, 8]
```

What is wrong with my code? How do I debug it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

did you create a variable named `str` or `len` anywhere?  If so, that's your problem.  (most likely, `len` since `str` was used earlier without any problem).

Python builtins are not reserved -- meaning that you are free to reassign them to any object that you want.  It looks like you assigned `len` to a long integer which makes sense because `len` is a perfectly reasonable variable name in other languages.

The thing you should take away from this is to be careful not to "shadow" builtin functions by creating variables of the same name.  It makes problems which can be hard to debug.

Comment: No problem.  Just be careful with your variable names :)

Comment: I was actually working with someone else's code base. Somebody's gonna get hurt real bad.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note: bare "except" clauses are the worst possible exception handling scheme - you just don't know what exception can happen, and you loose all the useful debugging informations stored in the exception's traceback. FWIW, sys.exit is actually implemented by raising a SysExit exception that is caught by the python runtime.

If you're in a loop and want to log infos about the exception for the current iteration and continue with next item, make sure you don't catch SysExit and learn to use the logging module :

```
import logging
# this will require some minimal conf somewhere, cf the fine manual
logger = logging.getLogger("my-logger-name")

def myfunction(somesequence):
    for item in somesequence:
        try:
            result = process(item)
        except Exception, e: 
            # in 'recent' python version this will not catch SysExit
            # please refer to the doc for your python version
            # if it's a slightly outdated version, uncomment the
            # following lines:
            # if isinstance(e, SysExit):
            #     raise
            logger.exception("got %s on item %s", e, item)
            continue
        else:
            # ok for this item
            do_something_with(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in a different context:

```
slope = (nsize*iopsum - (osum)(isum)) / (nsize*oopsum - (osum)*2)
```

of course the reason I was getting it was `(osum)(isum)` it was interpreting osum as a number and trying to call a different number on it. so after it was interpreted it looked something like this: 1513(3541) which doesn't make any sense.

I fixed it by adding in the * at the right location `(osum)*(isum)`